# ADB : How to turn on TV connected via HDMI or USB with terminal

Tags: android, linux, adb

I need to create a test script for Android TV (AOSP). Short description of the script: I must perform certain actions on the TV and after:

1. Turns off the TV (in StandBy mode), here i use `adb shell input keyevent 26`.
2. Timeout 1 minute.
3. Turns on the TV.

Problems arise in the point 3:

a) I use SecureCRT emulator and when the TV in StandBy, the console doesn't work.

b) When the TV in StandBy, android sleeps, so, it isn't adb command.

Which command can I turn on the TV?

Answer (score 1):

adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP

Comment: Worked like a charm.